# Not getting the role of the user from middleware while authencated

Tags: php, laravel

I want to direct the user to their dashboard, but before that, I need their role. I am not receiving the role from my middleware. I tried a relation between the tables but its not working.

**CustomerAuth Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CustomerAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        if (!auth()->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    else{
dd(auth()->user()->roles);
        foreach (auth()->user()->roles as $role){

            if ($role->slug == 'admin' || $role->slug == 'product-admin' || $role->slug == 'logistic-admin' ){

                return redirect()->route('customer.login-reset');
            }
        }


        foreach (auth()->user()->roles as $role){

            if ($role->slug == 'customer' ){

            return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
    }

}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table='users';
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','name', 'email', 'password','profile_image','role_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function  roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }


}
```

The [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7y6c.png) I encounter is trying to get the property of a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship looks OK. Maybe refactor the middleware a bit so it's more readable. What does `dd(auth()->user()->roles)` say? What line is it erroring out at?

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Closure;

class CustomerAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            foreach (auth()->user()->roles as $role) {
                if ($role->slug === 'admin' ||
                    $role->slug === 'product-admin' ||
                    $role->slug === 'logistic-admin') {

                    return redirect()->route('customer.login-reset');
                }
            }

            foreach (auth()->user()->roles as $role) {
                if ($role->slug === 'customer') {

                    return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard');
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}


// User.php
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
}

// Role.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

Then you can access the slug like so...

```
$user->role->slug;
```